# Elif syntax errors Python

Tags: python, syntax

I keep getting a syntax error with my `elif` line of code in Python.

I think it has something to do with the indentation but am not completely sure.

Here is my code:

[image: My code]

Comment: Show code, output and/or possible error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not by external link.

Comment: you are missing a `:`

Comment: `elif score2>score1:` not `elif score2>score1`. You're missing a colon

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this line:

```
elif score2>score 1
```

- You're missing a colon at the end.
- You have an extra space between `score` and `1` (your variable is named `score1`).

So this line should be:

```
elif score2 > score1:
```

Comment: Thanks. however not it is saying this. "value of _stdout is incorrect". what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
    # This is a def coz I want to run the code :)
    points_for_player_1 = 0
    points_for_player_2 = 0
    losses_for_player_1 = 0
    losses_for_player_2 = 0
    ties = 0



       if points_for_player_1 > points_for_player_2:
       losses_for_player_2 =+1
       points_for_player_1 =+1
       print("Player 1 wins , Score of the player is "+ points_for_player_1)
       elif points_for_player_1 < points_for_player_2:
       losses_for_player_1 =+1
       points_for_player_2 =+1
       print("Player 2 wins , Score of the player is "+ points_for_player_2)
       elif points_for_player_1 = points_for_player_2:
       ties =+1
       print("No one won , It's a tie !")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).